# Splitting up a string, c#

Tags: c#

i have a string that gets generated and looks like this:

word1:word2:word3:word4

the words i want to find out a seperated by ":"

so i coded the following:

```
string word1 = "";
string word2 = "";
string word3 = "";
string word4 = "";

int part = 1;
int last_sign = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < string1.Length; i++)
   {
       if (string1[i] == ':')
       {
          if (part == 2)
          {
           part = part + 1;
          }
       }
       if (part == 1)
       {
          word1 = word1 + string1[i];
       }
       if (part == 2)
       {
          word2 = word2 + string1[i];
       }
       if (part == 3)
       {
        word3 = word3 + string1[i];
       }
       if (part == 4)
       {
        word4 = word4 + string1[i];
       }
       if (last_sign == 0)
       {
        if (string1[i + 2] == (string1.Length - 3)) //this is the sign before the last sign 
                                                   //error line
        { last_sign = 1; }
       }
       if (last_sign == 1) //this is the last sign
        { break; }
 }
```

but when i try run it the right,complete words get read in, but i get an error (see above).
i hope some of you can point what i am doing wrong

Comment: Just use `string.Split(':')` instead of all that manual work

Comment: use the split method :D

Comment: Why are you comparing a character to a number?  I'm guessing the issue happens once `i + 2` is out of the range of the length of the string.  What's the point of `last_sign`?

Comment: What is your specific problem or error?

Comment: Instead of using variables like word1, word2, etc, you should definitely look into using a array or list. Otherwise the ohters got it right: string.Split() is the droid you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Split` method:

```
string[] words = string1.Split(':');
```

Now, you have all the words collected into an array which you can then enumerate upon or index into particular positions etc.

e.g.

```
foreach (var word in words)
       Console.WriteLine(word);
```

Comment: Shouldn't `str` be `word`?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Input string contain separators.
        string value1 = "word1:word2:word3:word4";
        char[] delimiter1 = new char[] { ':' };   // <-- Split on these

        // ... Use StringSplitOptions.None.
        string[] array1 = value1.Split(delimiter1,
            StringSplitOptions.None);

        foreach (string entry in array1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }

        // ... Use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries.
        string[] array2 = value1.Split(delimiter1,
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (string entry in array2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
char[] delim = {':'};
string[] words = string1.Split(delim);
```

Then access the elements of `words[]`